# Populate a datagridview from database on selection of an item in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox having the requisition number. now when i select 1 of the requisition item like r001 in the combobox its information should be populated in the datagrid below. i have used a stroed procedure for this. but i dont know how to bind the datagrid view control to the info.

code:

```
private void cmbreqno_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cmd.Connection = con;
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        txtcc.Text = "";
        int selection = Convert.ToInt16(((KeyValuePair<string, string>)(cmbreqno.SelectedItem)).Key);
        if (selection.ToString() != "")
        {

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "itemname";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_no", selection);
            dsitemname.Clear();
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dsitemname);
            txtcc.Text = dsitemname.Tables[1].Rows[0]["costcenter_no"].ToString();
            txtcc.Tag = dsitemname.Tables[1].Rows[0]["costcenter_id"].ToString();

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

stored procedure:

```
alter proc itemname
(
    @req_no int
)
as begin
select item_name,brand_name,quantity,requisitionitem.item_cost
from requisitionitem left outer join item
on requisitionitem.item_id=item.item_id
where requisitionitem.req_no=@req_no
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just databind your `DataTable` to `DataGridView`

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null; //clear old one
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); //remove old rows
dataGridView1.DataSource = dsitemname.Tables[0];
```

Comment: thank you. also can you tell me if i want to add more columns to these columns how should i do it?

Comment: You have to create yourself columns (with `DataPropertyName` set to corresponding column name from db if you want to fill them from data source) and also set `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`

Answer (score 0):

**It should be as follows:**

```
            con.Open();
            int selection = Convert.ToInt16(((KeyValuePair<string, string>)(cmbreqno.SelectedItem)).Key);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_no",selection);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Hope Its Helpful.